# Jetpack Compose - Row of images with a max height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I would like to implement a row of images with a maximum height of 15dp. If the screen is too thin to display the images with a height of 15dp, they should all be resized for the row to fit the screen width (images must always have the same height). I know it looks simple but I can't find a way to make it work.

Here is a quick graphic I made to explain what I want to achieve:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are missing the ratio of width to height. I assume the ratio is 10.

```kotlin
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .heightIn(max = 15.dp)
        .aspectRatio(10f)
) {
    listOf(
        1f to Color.Yellow,
        0.7f to Color.Red,
        1.5f to Color.Green,
        1f to Color.Black,
    ).forEach { (w, c) ->
        Box(
            modifier= Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .weight(w)
                .background(c)
        ) 
    }
}
```

[image]

If you set maxHeight to 1000dp to simulate a smaller screen, the width of Row will be limited to ScreenWidth.

[image]

---

I get it, you want to automatically determine the ratio based on the image size. In compose, the constraint is passed from the outside in, so it would be slightly unnatural to implement such a feature.

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)) {
        Test(3)
        Test(5)
        Test(15)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Test(times: Int) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .heightIn(max = 50.dp)
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .background(Color.Yellow),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
    ) {
        repeat(times) {
            val painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            Image(
                painter = painter,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .weight(
                        weight = painter.intrinsicSize.width / painter.intrinsicSize.height,
                        fill = false
                    )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I wish I could avoid computing width or ratio manually. On iOS with SwiftUI, you can achieve this with these simple lines:

`HStack {
  Image("apple").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(height: 15.0)
  Image("cherry").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(height: 15.0)
  Image("star").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(height: 15.0)
}`

Comment: The second part of your answer is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help!